# I have to filter out nested object based on condition in angular 14

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, angular5, angular14

Below is my json object in which I have nested listofdeciosion object. If listofdecisoion length is greater than 1 and it has decision name as 'AEE' then I have to remove that object from listofdecision and if length of decision is 1 and it has decisionname as 'AEE' then remove entire object. My logic is not working for else part

```js
[
   {
      "anomalyId":49, 
      "listOfDecision":[
         {
            "decisionId":69,
            "decisionName":"à reprendre",
         }
      ],
      "deleted":false
   },
   {
      "anomalyId":51,
      "listOfDecision":[
         {
            "decisionId":71,
            "decisionName":"Bride A1 Carter Fan",
         }
      ],
      "deleted":false
   },
   {
      "anomalyId":85,
      "listOfDecision":[
         {
            "decisionId":128,
            "decisionName":"AEE",
         }
      ],
      "deleted":false
   },
   {
      "anomalyId":81,
      "listOfDecision":[
         {
            "decisionId":121,
            "decisionName":"AEE",
         },
         {
            "decisionId":123,
            "decisionName":"à repeindre",
         },
         {
            "decisionId":122,
            "decisionName":"A Retoucher SOUS ITT",
         }
      ],
      "deleted":false
   },
   {
      "anomalyId":82,
      "listOfDecision":[
         {
            "decisionId":124,
            "decisionName":"AEE",
         }
      ],
      "deleted":false
   }
]
```

```js
public hideAEEDecisionRow(res){
    //let tempDataSource = [];
    this.tempDataSource = [...res];
    this.tempDataSource.forEach((item, index) => {
      const tempListOfDecision = [...item.listOfDecision];
      if (item.listOfDecision.length === 1) {
        if (item.listOfDecision[0].decisionName === 'AEE') {
          this.tempDataSource.splice(index, 1);
        }
      } else {
        console.log("here in else")
        tempListOfDecision.forEach((decision, decisionIndex) => {
          if (decision.decisionName === 'AEE') {
            tempListOfDecision.splice(decisionIndex, 1);
          }
          console.log("tempListOfDecision =>",tempListOfDecision)
        })
        item.listOfDecision = tempListOfDecision;
      }
    });
    this.dataSource = this.tempDataSource;
    console.log("tempDataSource =>",this.tempDataSource);
    // // call list of decisions method
    this.assignListOfdecisionsToAllObjects(this.tempDataSource);
    console.log("viewAllDataSource=>",this.viewAllDataSource);
  }
```